# Android star another activity from action bar

Tags: java, android, xml

so I'm working on this app of mine and I'm kinda stuck with the action bar item to respond to onclick. I think the xml is alright giving:

```
android:onClick="move"
```

With this in the main activity:

```
public void move(){
Intent i;
i = new Intent(Launch.this, MoveClass.class);
Launch.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Note:Intent is declared as import; When trying to run the button doesn't display and after about 2 seconds my tablet says it's crashed.

Comment: Post the logcat stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Maybe exception stack trace could help to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [developer article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), you should have a method with `MenuItem` parameter.

So maybe this new method would do the job:

```
public void move(MenuItem myMItem) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Launch.this, MoveClass.class);
    Launch.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: You're a saver, I've seen people doing it with View, but I didn't understans. Thanks :)